# Changes made to powercfg.exe saved on your harddrive?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, powercfg

Seems like a silly question and I am about 80% sure it does, but I cant find it documented anywhere.

Lets say 1 of my laptops is stuck in sleep mode, I remove the hard drive and put it in a similar laptop. There I change a setting to `powercfg -h off` and put the hard drive back in laptop 1.

Is the setting `powercfg -h off` applied on laptop 1 as well?

Just a quick confirmation or rejection will sufice! Thanks

Comment: You must mean it's hibernating, but what do you mean by "stuck"? What is the behavior of the original machine when you try to boot it?

Comment: Yeah I meant hibernating. But basicly all I want to know is whether the setting you apply on the hard drive of laptop 1, while it is placed in laptop 2, will still be applied when you put the hard drive back in laptop 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you boot laptop 1's drive in laptop 2, then yes, doing a powercfg -h will disable the hibernation feature when the drive is place back into laptop 1, since it's a registry setting in Windows and not stored on the drive or BIOS or anything like that.

However, if you did that -- even if laptop 2 is an identical model -- it would cause the whole operating system to reconfigure itself.  Twice.  Windows doesn't like being moved to different hardware.  Worst case scenario is that it could corrupt your whole Windows install.

The preferred way to fix this scenario (i.e. if laptop 1 won't resume properly), would be to plug it into another computer as a **secondary** drive (e.g. putting it into a USB enclosure or whatever) and delete the HIBERFIL.SYS file in the root directory.  Returning it to laptop 1 would make it boot fresh at that point and then you could issue your powercfg -h off to disable the hibernation feature.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize it was bad for the windows install since the laptops were identical. I'll use the fix you suggest with the secondary drive from now on!